# Delete rows in a table that has multiple FKs

Tags: sql-server-2005, query, delete

I need to delete all the rows in the `ContentData` table that have the word 'DV95' in the `htmldata` column.

Here is what I am using:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DELETE Contentdata
FROM Contentlinks INNER JOIN contenttasks 
   ON contentdata.contentid = contenttasks.contentid
WHERE contentdata.htmldata LIKE '%DV95%'
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is there problem in the syntax?
2. It keeps showing me a number of FK contraint issues due to number of table dependencies. How do I delete these rows?

Comment: You can use SSMS's 'Parse' button (the blue check mark) to check the syntax without running the query.  Also, you need to close your transaction with a commit.

Comment: That is how I got this error message. I didn't run the query yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If I got you right - you need to delete referencing rows prior to deleting the referenced rows.

```
begin transaction
DELETE Contenttasks
FROM contentdata
 where contentdata.contentid = contenttasks.contentid 
and contentdata.htmldata LIKE '%DV95%'

Delete from contentdata where htmldata like '%dv95%'
Commit
```

Comment: Well, yes! hope this helps -- Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'. -- I got this error when running the query (contentdata, contenttasks and contentlinks are tables)

Comment: by the way, i really appreciate your response and for your time. Thanks!!

Comment: Oleg's answer is correct, but you may be able to make use of "ON DELETE CASCADE" in your tables definition. Search for "DELETE CASCADE" and your db engine of choice.

Comment: Corrected the small mistake, try it.